# Stuck up with routes and collections. Nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections basically. Roomlist and Userlist.  I want to show roomlist and userlist together. I need to show it inside a page named as "userlist"..But it is not working. If i kept collection in separate pages it is working.

```
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {


var db = req.db;


var userName = req.body.username;
var userTime = req.body.usertime;
var userEmail = req.body.useremail;


var collection = db.get('usercollection');


collection.insert({
    "username" : userName,"usertime":userTime,
    "email" : userEmail
}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {

        res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
    }
    else {

   res.redirect("example");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely clear in your question, but if you want to have two collections on a single page:

```
var collectionUserList = [];
var collectionRoomlist = [];
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  db.collection("collectionUserList", function(err, collection) {

      db.collection("collectionRoomlist", function(err, collection) {

      });

      res.render('/userlist', {
        collection: collectionUserList ,
        collectionRoomlist: collectionRoomlist
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your beloved answer. Is it like callback function and i explored a little to know about callback hell but not so clear about async until now. If you have any good material then it would be great.

Comment: Callbacks and Async are the most important concepts to understand when writing Node and client side interfaces to it!  Are you looking for more tutorials about that?

Comment: would be thrilled for some tutorials